# Compress range of numbers into blocks of used or unused

Tags: algorithms

Given a numerical range and a list of used numbers that fall within that range I need to compress the range into blocks of used and unused numbers.

For example:

```
range: 0 to 10
used:  3,4,5,9
```

I need an output like

```
0-2: free
3-5: used
6-8: free
9:   used
10:  free
```

Not sure where to start with this, so any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Have you written any code or pseudocode yet? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Is the list of used numbers ordered?

Comment: this is very similar to run length encoding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, this is very similar to [run length encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), in fact if `used` is sorted it is arguably a bit easier!

With run length encoding you would start with the first number in an array and scan forward counting the number between each transition between used/unused (or in your case recording the start and end index which is essentially equivalent).

However if used is sorted you already know where the first transition from unused->used is so you can start there and scan `used` for the next transition from used->unused, you then also know the next unused->used transition as its the next `used` number.

if `used` isn't sorted you could either sort it first (likely a good idea if used is small compared to `range`) or you could use `range` and `used` to first construct a full array of used and unused numbers e.g. `00011100010` and run length encode this.

Comment: I've sorted this in a simple way by just scanning the the whole range and checking if every number is in used. as the size of range and used is small this is inexpensive. Thanks